# How to send SOAP(xml over http) Post request and parse result using libcurl

Tags: c, http, soap, libcurl

I am trying to connect a C program to a SOAP Server all running in localhost.

I have this test example but I don't know how to integrate it into my C code with libcurl:

```
POST /otd HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: OT
Host: localhost:9002
Content-Length: 196
Connection: Close

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <doSome/>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Here is a libcurl example that I found, but can't figure out how to integrate my xml Post that I provided above and how to get response and parse it on my own:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>

#define URL "localhost:9002"

size_t write_data(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmeb, void *stream)
{
    return fwrite(ptr,size,nmeb,stream);
}

size_t read_data(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmeb, void *stream)
{
    return fread(ptr,size,nmeb,stream);
}

int sendMessage (char * inFile, char * outFile) {
    //writing to file initially
    FILE * rfp = fopen(inFile, "r");
    if(!rfp) {
        perror("Read File Open:");
//        exit(0);
    }

    FILE * wfp = fopen(outFile, "w+"); //File pointer to write the soap response
    if(!wfp) {
        perror("Write File Open:");
//        exit(0);
    }

    struct curl_slist *header = NULL;
    header = curl_slist_append (header, "POST /otd HTTP/1.1");
    header = curl_slist_append (header, "User-Agent: OpenTrackDispatcher");
    header = curl_slist_append (header, "Host: localhost:9002");
    header = curl_slist_append (header, "Content-Length: 196");
    header = curl_slist_append (header, "Connection: Close");

    CURL *curl;
    CURLcode res;

    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if(curl) {
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, URL);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1L);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_READFUNCTION, read_data);  //Reads xml file to be sent via POST operation
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_READDATA, rfp); 
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_data);  //Gets data to be written to file
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, wfp);  //Writes result to file
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, header);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE_LARGE, (curl_off_t)-1);
//        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE,1L);            
        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);

        return 1;
    }
};
```

ps: my module needs to continuously request data from the SOAP server (each second!)..

Comment: What is `write_data`? If it is not NULL, than the comment `Writes result to file` looks wrong.

Comment: That's what I didn't get from the code, it's not mine I got it from here (stackoverflow) someone claiming that it works for him but it looks wrong!

Comment: @S.M. I am also looking into gsoap but can't find any examples except the one in the documentation but it doesn't fit my need!